# Sheet custom methods not usable using variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have defined a few methods and properties behind an Excel sheet (Sheet10).
if I call `Sheet10.SortData` from another normal module, it works fine.
However if i use the code below, it does not compile.
**Why** ?? Is there a workaround ?

works:

```
Sheet10.SortData
```

compile error:

```
dim shM as worksheet
set shM = Sheet10
shM.SortData
```

Comment: Have you tried with `Worksheets(shM.Name).SortData`?

Comment: please try  `Dim shM As Variant`.

Comment: @Maddy Perfect! please make it an answer. Thx !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try like this

```
    Dim shM As Variant
    Set shM = Sheet10 
    shM.SortData
```

Comment: or just `Dim shM`

Answer (score 1):

SortData appears to be a sub procedure on Sheet10's private code sheet. You're losing the reference to the code sheet when assigning a variable to the worksheet object's [CodeName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-codename-property-excel).

Comment: For instance, @Maddy's solution to use a `Variant` works great at runtime. Only drawback is  that you lose autocompletion.